# What’s wrong with my strategy for this number-theoretic game?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

The game is defined as follows.

> Starting with a positive integer $N$, you can repeatedly perform one of two operations on $N$:
>
> - If **$N=ab$**, replace $N$ by $\max(a,b)$.
> - Subtract $1$ from $N$.
>
> Find the minimum number of operations required to reduce $N$ to $0$.

After working for few $N$'s, I got that for any **composite** $N$, we can reduce $N$ to zero in a minimal number of steps if we change $N=\max(a,b) $ , where $ (a,b) $ is the pair in which $N=ab$, and $b$ is as small as possible, and $a \leq b$. For any **prime** $N$, we can only subtract 1, and continue with $N-1$.

For instance, if $N=48$, the pair described above is $(6, 8)$, leading to the solution

$$ 48 \to 8 \to 4 \to 2 \to 1 \to 0 $$

which is 5 moves long.

My strategy seems to be invalid. Why is that?

Comment: From $2$ how do you reach $1$? For any prime $p$, $\max(a,b)=p$, and hence you are stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: This question, with addition allowed too, was [Erich Friedman's May 2001 Problem of the Month](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/0501.html).

Comment: @GoodDeeds Just subtract 1?

Comment: Counterexample:  82->41->40->8->4->2->1->0 is longer than 82->81->9->3->2->1->0.  Does that help?

Comment: @Gabriel Burns :Yes that really helped ! Now I can proceed towards solution.

Comment: Mathematically this is not easy, but if that is a programming problem this is very easy providing $N<10^5$, about that. So this is probably not suitable for this site. Also about $\LaTeX$ you should use `\times` $\times$ instead of $*$ and `\to` $\to$ instead of $->$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, the question was edited subsequently.